# Free control - Hybrid LinkLabel and HtmlTextBlock for Silverlight 3

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-3.0

I need a simple HTML renderer ( like HtmlTexBlock ) which also allows to intercept click on custom defined link ( like LinkLabel ) looking like hyperlink. Does anything like that exist as free software ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any but if you only want one link in your html text could you maybe  template a button using the htmltextblock as the content and capture the click event and navigate to desired page.  I know it will not work if you have multiple links in your html text however it is unclear what your exact requirment is.

eg.

```
<Button x:Name="btnhtml" Width="63" >
         <htmltextblock Text="Hello World"></htmltextblock>
</Button>
```